# Order preserving bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\lbrace{0}\rbrace$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

- How can one prove the existence of an order preserving bijection from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\lbrace{0}\rbrace$?
- Can you give an example of such a bijection?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Q}^*$?  Nonzero rationals?

Comment: Yes. Is $\mathbb{Q}\backslash\lbrace{0}\rbrace$ better?

Comment: @Eliott: Yes, much.

Comment: The quickest way to an _existence_ proof is of course to know that all countable dense linear orders without first or last elements are isomorphic...

Comment: You really ought to say something about what you've tried, but have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the proof of theorem 3.7 here: http://www.math.wustl.edu/~freiwald/ch8.pdf

Answer (score 16):

Choose an irrational number $\alpha$.

Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ be a strictly *increasing* sequence of rational numbers that converge towards $\alpha$.

Let $y_1, y_2, \ldots$ be a strictly *decreasing* sequence of rational numbers that converge towards $\alpha$.

Then define $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q\setminus\{0\}$ as:

- $f$ maps $(-\infty,x_1]$ to $(-\infty,-1]$ by subtracting $x_1+1$ from everything.
- For every $n$, $f$ maps $[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ to $[-\frac1n,-\frac1{n+1}]$, by linear interpolation between the endpoints.
- For every $n$, $f$ maps $[y_{n+1},y_n]$ to $[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]$, by linear interpolation between the endpoints.
- $f$ maps $[y_1,\infty)$ to $[1,\infty)$ by subtracting $y_1-1$ from everything.